# Read XML message from Kafka topic in Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, apache-spark-2.0

I need to consume XML messages from a Kafka topic and load into a Spark Dataframe within my foreachRDD block in streaming. How can I do that? I am able to consume JSON messages in my streaming job by doing `spark.sqlContext.read.json(rdd)`; What is the analogous code for reading XML format messages from Kafka? I am using Spark 2.2, Scala 2.11.8 and Kafka 0.10

My XML messages will have about 400 fields (heavily nested) so I want to dynamically store them in a DF in the `stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>  ... }` block and then operate on the DF.

Also should I convert the XML into JSON or Avro before sending into the topic at the producer end? Is that heavy to send XMLs as-is and is it better to send JSON instead?